# Rest Azure Endpoint not found

Tags: c#, rest, azure, windows-phone

I realize a service in Azure and to do that I followed this tutorial: [Rest with azure](http://tinyurl.com/6vtolt6)

The service works great but I have a problem of definition of endpoint (Endpoint not found.)

Yet I try to change my port in 8080 but no improvement.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ServiceDefinition name="FamilyMateAzureProject" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition">
      <WebRole name="FamilyMateService" vmsize="Small">
        <Sites>
          <Site name="Web">
            <Bindings>
              <Binding name="Endpoint" endpointName="Endpoint" />
            </Bindings>
          </Site>
        </Sites>
        <Endpoints>
          <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint" protocol="http" port="8080"/>
        </Endpoints>
        <Imports>
          <Import moduleName="Diagnostics" />
        </Imports>
        <LocalResources>
          <LocalStorage name="FamilyMateService.svclog" sizeInMB="1000" cleanOnRoleRecycle="false" />
        </LocalResources>
      </WebRole>
    </ServiceDefinition>
```

And when I try to add the reference of my service in another project (windows phone 7)

I get the following error:

*There Was an error downloading 'http://familymate.cloudapp.net:8080/FamilyMate.svc'.
The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
Metadata contains a reference That Can not Be resolved: 'http://familymate.cloudapp.net:8080/FamilyMate.svc'.
There Was No endpoint listening at http://familymate.cloudapp.net:8080/FamilyMate.svc That Could accept the message. This Is Often Caused by incorrect address or SOAP year action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
The remote server Returned an error: (404) Not Found.
If the service is Defined in the current solution, try building the solution and Adding the service reference again.*

In order not to be too bothered by the problem is I use RestSharp and created queries by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be a binding problem.  I would check out this and see if following these steps helps:

http://bartreyserhove.blogspot.com/2010/08/update-writing-windows-phone-7.html